# News web part filter not working on mobile Android app

Tags: sharepoint-online, app, newsfeed, mobile

I have a filter set up on a news web part on my site, but when viewing this list of news in the SharePoint Android app, the items are *not* filtered. Is there a way to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What filter do you use?

Per my test, I could not reproduce your issue when I add a simple filter in news web part, SharePoint android app will display filtered news successfully.

[image]

Please make sure you have published the page after editing, if the issue still exists, switch to other mobile phones to compare the result.

Comment: It's working today, I guess it might have been a caching issue... not sure. I will update this post if it stops working.